Faster way to find self-intersections of the curve parameterized by $(-4t^3-6t^2,-3t^4-4t^3)$

Given is a curve $K$ with $K(t)=\begin{pmatrix}f(t)\\g(t) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-4t^{3}-6t^{2}\\-3t^{4}-4t^{3} \end{pmatrix}$ and $-1.5 \leq t \leq 0.5$. I want to find the intersection of the curve with itself.

I know that I have to find the solutions to $f(t)=f(s)$ and $g(t)=g(s)$ for $t \neq s$.
This can be done by calculating the solutions $f(t)-f(s)=0$ and since $s=t$ is a solution one can solve $\dfrac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s}=0$ for $s$ and plug this expression for $s$ into the equation $g(t)=g(s)$. We get
$$t_1=0, s_1=0 \text{ (which is not the solution) and }t_2=\dfrac{-\sqrt{3}-1}{2}, s_2=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2} \text{(the solution)}$$
But the solution is very tedious. I saw that the solution is also the solution to $f(t)=f(-0.5)$ and $t=-0.5$ is the inflection point. Is this coincidence? Or is there a faster way to solve this problem?


One point to indicate why this is tricky to work out: Let $F(s,t)=(f(t)-f(s))/(t-s), G(s,t)=(g(t)-f(s))/(t-s)$. Then the curves $F(s,t)=G(s,t)=0$ both meet and are tangent at $t=s=0$.

Instead of comparing parameters $t$ and $s$, use $t=u\pm v$, as it's easier to discard $v=0$ as soon as it appears, rather than to find after various calculations that candidate $t$ and $s$ values match; moreover, the symmetry happens to simplify things a bit ... and even allows us to ignore $v<0$.
So, we start with
$$\begin{align}
f(u-v)=f(u+v) \quad\to\quad 0 &= 3 u\phantom{^2} + 3 u^2 + \phantom{3u}v^2 \tag1\\[4pt]
g(u-v)=g(u+v) \quad\to\quad 0 &= 3 u^2 + 3 u^3 + 3 u v^2 + v^2 \tag2 \\[4pt]
&= \phantom{2}u \cdot (\text{eq }1) \;+\;v^2(2u+1) \tag{2'} \\[4pt]
\to\quad 0 &= 2u+1 \tag{2''} 
\end{align}$$
where I've removed factors of $v$ and $v^2$.
From $(2'')$, we find $u=-1/2$; then, from $(1)$, $v=\sqrt{3}/2$ (ignoring the negative, which returns in the next step, anyway). Therefore, $t=-\left(1\pm\sqrt{3}\right)/2$, with each value corresponding to the self-intersection point $(-1,-1/4)$. Done!

(See the Edit History for an unnecessarily-lengthy argument and commentary using $t$ and $t+u$.)

 The implicitization of this rational quartic is $F=27x^4+32x^3-24x^2y+384xy^2+256y^3+432y^2=0,$ from which you can find two cusps besides a node at $(-1,-\frac14)$ The Hessian $H=0$ intersects $F=0$ only in the singular points.
R=QQ[s,t,x,y,z,MonomialOrder=>Eliminate 2]
I=ideal(x-(-4*t^3*s-6*t^2*s^2),y-(-3*t^4-4*t^3*s),z-s^4)
gens gb I
F=oo_0_0 -- 27*x^4+32*x^3*z-24*x^2*y*z+384*x*y^2*z+256*y^3*z+432*y^2*z^2  
f = map(QQ[x,y],R,{0,0,x,y,1})
G=f F -- 27*x^4+32*x^3-24*x^2*y+384*x*y^2+256*y^3+432*y^2 
J=ideal(diff(x,G),diff(y,G),G)
primaryDecomposition oo -- {
 ideal(y,x^2), 
 ideal(x+y+1,(y-1)^2), 
 ideal(4*y+1,x+1)}
 use R
H=determinant matrix{{diff(x,diff(x,F)),diff(y,diff(x,F)),diff(z,diff(x,F))},{diff(x,diff(y,F)),diff(y,diff(y,F)),diff(z,diff(y,F))},{diff(x,diff(z,F)),diff(y,diff(z,F)),diff(z,diff(z,F))}}
GH=f H


The Hessian $H=0$ intersects $F=0$ only in the singular points - can you explain this? Is this a general statement / theorem?

@garondal It's about this particular case, just to nudge you into seeing that there are no proper flexes.

[+1] Maybe it would be useful to say that your program is written with Sage (so I think...).

@JeanMarie M2 or Macaulay2, but there’s an interface with sage, yes.

Thanks for your answer. I should have guessed.

I have something in my mind, hope this helps:
Consider that, the curve intersects itself at different values of $t$, say $t_1$ and $t_2$. At these two points, the value of the curve must be same, which leads to the first equation:
$$-4t_1^3-6t_1^2=-4t_2^3-6t_2^2$$
Arranging the terms and considering that $t_1\neq t_2$ [since they are supposed to be different points], we arrive at:
$$4(t_1^3-t_2^3)=6(t_2^2-t_1^2)$$
$$\Rightarrow 2(t_1-t_2)(t_1^2+t_1t_2+t_2^2)=-3(t_1-t_2)(t_1+t_2)$$$$
\Rightarrow 2(t_1^2+t_1t_2+t_2^2)=-3(t_1+t_2)$$
Also working with the second equation, we can arrive at:
$$-3t_1^4-4t_1^3=-3t_2^4-4t_2^3$$
After a bit of rearrangement, we arrive at:
$$\Rightarrow3t_1^3+3t_1^2t_2+3t_1t_2^2+3t_2^3+4(t_1^2+t_1t_2+t_2^2)=0$$
Plugging the value of $2(t_1^2+t_1t_2+t_2^2)$ from the fist equation into the second, we get:
$$3t_1^3+3t_1^2t_2+3t_1t_2^2+3t_2^3-6t_1-6t_2=0$$
Taking out the common factor, we can rewrite:
$$t_1^3+t_1^2t_2+t_1t_2^2+t_2^3-2t_1-2t_2=0$$
Now, this is where I need to do a bit of work. Since the interference term $t_1t_2$ is a bit of intricating, it is best to get rid of it as early as possible. The first step is:
$$t_1^3+t_1t_2(t_1+t_2)+t_2^3-2(t_1+t_2)=0$$
Apply the formula, $(t_1^3+t_2^3)=(t_1+t_2)^3-3(t_1t_2)(t_1+t_2)$ and plugin the values of $t_1^3+t_2^3$ from the previous equation into this:
$$2(t_1+t_2)-t_1t_2(t_1+t_2)=(t_1+t_2)^3-3t_1t_2(t_1+t_2)$$
$$(t_1+t_2)^3-2t_1t_2(t_1+t_2)-2(t_1+t_2)=0$$
Either $(t_1+t_2)=0$ or
$$(t_1+t_2)^2-2t_1t_2-2=0$$
$$\Rightarrow2t_1t_2=(t_1+t_2)^2-2$$
Now, use this equation and put in $2(t_1^2+t_1t_2+t_2^2)=-3(t_1+t_2)$ to get:
$$(t_1+t_2)^2+3(t_1+t_2)+2=0$$
Take this as a quadratic equation of $x$ and we may find solutions like:
$$t_1+t_2=-1$$or,$$t_1+t_2=-2$$
Now, we can put $t_2=-t_1-1$ in the equation $t_1^2+t_2^2=2$ to find the solutions:
$$t_1=\frac{-\sqrt3-1}{2}$$
$$t_2=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2}$$
Also, note that another solution do exist, $t_1=t_2=-1$
I do not think as easier solution except these rigorous algebra does exist.

The "solution" $t_1=t_2=-1$ corresponds to the same point  on the original curve and thus does not represent a self-intersection.
